# Glassfish: How to do asadmin commands without password?

Tags: linux, glassfish

every time I enter a CLI-command for glassfish like this `asadmin start-instance i1` I am prompted to enter the admin-username and admin-password.

How can I disable the need for entering these credentials?

I plan to write scripts for running commands like this and I think it's not possible to enter the credentials in a bash script.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the password from a file instead of entering the password at the command line.

The --passwordfile option takes the file containing the passwords:

```
AS_ADMIN_PASSWORD=value
AS_ADMIN_ADMINPASSWORD=value
AS_ADMIN_USERPASSWORD=value
AS_ADMIN_MASTERPASSWORD=value
```

Comment: -W shorter for --passwordfile

Answer (score 10):

The password file option is perhaps to verbose.

Simply do the following:

1. asadmin start-domain mydomain
2. asadmin login

Put in the admin user name and the admin password.

In your user home directory a file will get created

".asadminpass] successfully.
Make sure that this file remains protected.
Information stored in this file will be used by
asadmin commands to manage the associated domain.
Command login executed successfully."